# Getting user data after the Facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this page where I am doing testing

http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php

The button works fine - it lets me log in and out of Facebook, but I don't know anything about this user, so its kind of pointless.

What I need to do it pull their first_name, last_name, email, lat, lng from their FB.
I had code like this before, but it just broke my site:

```
$message = "Apps on Facebook.com are cool!";

$feed_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=".$app_id."&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)
                . "&message=" . $message;

 if (empty($_REQUEST["post_id"])) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $feed_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
    echo ("Feed Post Id: " . $_REQUEST["post_id"]);
 }
```

What can I do to pull the data I need for the account?

By the way, my FB login button setup looks like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=my_id&amp;xfbml=1">
</script><fb:login-button show-faces="false" perms="user_hometown,user_about_me,email,user_address" autologoutlink="true" width="200" max-rows="1">
</fb:login-button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the user is authenticated you can make graph calls against the special `me` object:

**PHP**

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me');
$detailObj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($detailObj);
```

**JavaScript**

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);  //response is the basic user object
});
```

[More on FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)

[More on available graph objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: the calls would be in JS? So essentially, I'd pull the data, and use AJAX to insert/validate the user in my db?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just presumed JS.  You can do the same kind of thing in PHP, let me edit...

Comment: Actually, it seems that JS might make more sense because I'll need to validate the user using an AJAX call.  Curious how it would work in php.

Comment: `me` is a short form that asks for the user object.  It can be considered interchangeable with the user id of the logged in user.

Comment: Also, I think my PHP is a little old. I think you can just use file_get_contents then break up the resulting json.